# How to get caret positon in a text with AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to assign a hotkey to do 3 clicks where the caret position is in a text to select a paragraph from a text on "Anki Add editor" (I don't want to press 3 clicks by mouse).

For this purpose :

1. I want to know how to get the caret position in a text
2. Moving the mouse cursor to the caret position in a text
3. Doing 3 clicks

Somthing like this:

```
AppsKey::
CaretPosition := 
GetCaretPosition X and Y 
MouseMove, %CaretPosition%
Click 3
Return
```

Please help! . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Built-in Variables **A_CaretX**, **A_CaretY**:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#misc)

> A_CaretX and A_CaretY are the current X and Y coordinates of the caret
> (text insertion point).
>
> The coordinates are relative to the active window unless CoordMode is
> used to make them relative to the entire screen.
>
> If there is no active window or the caret position cannot be
> determined, these variables are blank.

Mooving the mouse cursor to the caret position:

```
MouseMove, A_CaretX, A_CaretY, 0
```

Comment: A_CaretX and A_CaretY variables not working in Chrome. Any solution to this?